# How to get a given number of unique combinations of layers variations, while maintaining a given proportion of each layer variant using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I need to write a script in Python to solve this task, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have items (let's name them layers): A, B, C...

Each layer can have any number of variations.

For each variation, the proportion percent is given that we want to get at the output.

At the output, we have to get a given number of unique combinations of all layers according to the given proportions.

For example:

```
layers = [
   {'A0':'30%', 'A1':'30%', 'A2':'40%'},
   {'B0':'10%', 'B1': '20%', 'B2' '40%', 'B3':'30%'},
   {'C0':'50%'}
]
```

If I want to get exact 10 unique combinations of the A, B, C layers variations,
the script should output the dataset like this:

```
[
    ('A0', 'B0'), 
    ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), 
    ('A0', 'B1'), 
    ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), 
    ('A1', 'B2'), 
    ('A1', 'B3', 'C0'), 
    ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), 
    ('A2', 'B2'), 
    ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), 
    ('A2', 'B3')
]
```

So, the counts of each layer variation should align with the given proportions:

```
A0 = 3, A1 = 3, A2 = 4
B0 = 1, B1 = 2, B2 = 4, B3 = 3,
C0 = 5
```

If we want to get 20 variations the counts will be different:

```
A0 = 6, A1 = 6, A2 = 8
B0 = 2, B1 = 4, B2 = 8, B3 = 6,
C0 = 10
```

It should work for any number of layers, variations, proportions and get the exact count of the output combinations
(or the maximum of combinations, if there are no more combinations to get the exact number)

Comment: What is the criteria for aligning row distributions where the frequency < 100% i.e what is the logic for joining `C0` with  `'A0', 'B1'` and not `'A0', 'B0'`? Also, can the order of the layers vary with each combination? For instance, is `['A0', 'A2', 'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A0', 'A1', 'A1']` a valid possible layer for `A`?

Comment: There are no special criteria. C0 can be joined to any combination. The order of layers doesn't matter.
The main criteria:
1. Preserved proportion
2. Exact given number of combinations (or maximum of possibles)
3. Uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

For every layer, you can find the distribution list and then recursively merge the results to produce the combinations. Due to the very high number of combinations that could result from `get_combos`, the latter is a generator, and you can use `next` to produce the values on-demand:

```
import itertools
layers = [{'A0': '30%', 'A1': '30%', 'A2': '40%'}, {'B0': '10%', 'B1': '20%', 'B2': '40%', 'B3': '30%'}, {'C0': '50%'}]
def layer_combos(l, d):
  return [i for a, b in l.items() for i in ([a]*int((d*(int(b[:-1])/float(100)))))]

def get_offsets(l, d, c = []):
   if not d:
      yield tuple(c)
   else:
      if l:
         yield from get_offsets(l[1:], d-1, c+[l[0]])
      if not c or c[-1] is not None:
         for i in range(d - len(l)):
             yield from get_offsets(l, d-(i+1), c+([None]*(i+1)))

def get_combos(l, d, c = []):
  if not l:
     if len((l:=[tuple(list(filter(None, i))) for i in zip(*c)])) == len(set(l)):
        yield l
  else:
     for i in itertools.permutations((l1:=layer_combos(l[0], d)), (l2:=len(l1))):
        for j in set(get_offsets(i, d)):
           yield from get_combos(l[1:], d, c + [j])
           

result = get_combos(layers, 10)
for _ in range(10): #first ten combinations
  print(next(result))
```

Output:

```
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0')]
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0')]
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Your code is very elegant!
I've tested it with another dataset, but it generates repeated combinations: layers = [
    {'A0': '30%', 'A1': '10%', 'A2': '30%', 'A3': '30%'},
    {'B0': '100%'},
    {'C0': '30%', 'C1': '30%', 'C2': '30%', 'C3': '10%'},
    {'D0': '50%', 'D1': '50%'},
    {'E0': '10%'},
]

Comment: I tried your last edit. But even in your example, there are repetitions. In the first line of the output, combinations ('A1', 'B2', 'C0') and ('A2', 'B3') are repeated: [('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A0', 'B1', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B2', 'C0'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B3', 'C0')]

Comment: @Serhii I think the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) applies here. Depending your input proportions and ordering rules, it is quite possible that no set of unique layer ordering combinations could be found. Regardless, please see my recent edit, as I updated the solution to eliminate combinations with non-unique elements.